# Is this integral notation correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, notation

In the [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) article on Wikipedia, the mathematical derivation chapter:
$$J = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}\, dt
 = \int_{p_1}^{p_2} d\mathbf{p}
= \mathbf{p_2} - \mathbf{p_1} = \Delta \mathbf{p}$$

As someone noticed in the article's [Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Impulse_(physics)):

> After the "therefore" statement in the "Mathematical derivation in the
>   case of an object of constant mass" section, a misuse of notation is
>   used to seemingly "cancel out" the 'dt's in the integration
>   expression,. This should instead be a statement of the Second
>   Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to derive the impulse-momentum
>   theorem. While the "cancelling" is a subtlety that provides the
>   correct results, it could mislead readers. A change could look like
>   $$I = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}\, dt
>  = \mathbf{p_2} - \mathbf{p_1}
>  = \Delta \mathbf{p}$$

Which notation is correct here?

Comment: If $\mathbf{p_2}$ and $\mathbf{p_1}$ equal $\mathbf{p}(t_2)$ and $\mathbf{p}(t_1)$, respectively, then the second one is correct and the first one is wrong. This is assuming the symbols are being used with their standard meanings. **Edit:** See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio) related question.

Comment: This sort of notation is used very frequently. The "cancelling" is a symbolic representation of what is commonly called u-substitution now, but in a different form.